# jQuery code removeAttr issue

Tags: jquery, attributes

```
<input id="mnc" type="text"/>
<input type="text" id="selected" />
```

---

```
$('#mnc').val().length ? $('#selected').attr({
    'size': $('#mnc').val()
}) : $('#selected').removeAttr('size');
```

This gives an error in Firefox 4.

> Index or size is negative or greater
>   than the allowed amount" code: "1

Other browsers are able to handle `removeAttr` even if attribute does not exist. What i'm doing is checking if input #mnc is empty then remove attribute size from `#selected` whether it exists or not.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/zFCtU/1/

Comment: any particular reason why you are not checking if it exists before removing the attr?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue. Even if size attribute exists, i'm still getting the error in firefox 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Firefox, see the [jQuery bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8117). A workaround should be present for `jQuery Version >= 1.6`.

Edit: Sadly the fix is to be released with 1.6 (not 1.5.2 as I wrote earlier). Firefox 4.0.1 should fix it on the firefox-side though. You either have to decide to expect that 4.0.1 is installed of have to apply the patch yourself.

Comment: Thanks, i guess will have to wait for jQuery 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

here is a snippet to look at, it's working

```
$('#mnc').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $('#selected').attr({'size': $(this).val().length});
    } else {
        $('#selected').removeAttr('size');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try setting it first then unsetting it, to make sure it always exists?

```
$('#selected').attr('size','').removeAttr('size');
```